# Double click the shell script in linux

Tags: shell

I created one shell script in linux which will set the shell user defined varibles, run the .jar file with port and will open the firefox with port mentioned.

1. The script is executing successfully and it's working as expected
   when I executed the script through terminal(i.e., sh name.sh or
   ./name.sh)
2. If I double click the shell script and from the dialog window if
   I clicked the button "Run" it's working fine as expected.
3. If I double click the shell script and from the dialog window if
   I clicked the button "Run in Terminal" it's executing the commands
   and the terminal is closed even though the process of jar is not
   existing after the terminal is closed.

Note : the .jar is running when terminal is alive not after the terminal is closed.

Answer (score 0):

you should say `sh java -jar <<jarfile>>` this will open the java process in a new shell which will not close with the terminal which started the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the variable in the script file.

example:
`export PATH=/PATH/TO/SET`

This will make sure that the variables defined will be in effect out side the shell as well.